# Call button click event ajax loaded user control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've add usercontrol in my aspx page by ajax call, UserControl UI loaded successfully but its click event is not firing.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Test.aspx/UserControl",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    load: target.substring(1)
  }),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(uc) {
    $('#results').html('').html(uc.d);
  },
  failure: function(msg) {
    //error
  }
});
```

[WebMethod]

```
    public static string UserControl(string load)
    {
        using (Page page = new Page())
        {
            UserControl userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl("UserControls/ucgTest.ascx");
            page.Controls.Add(userControl);
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                page.Controls.Add(userControl);
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: trigger its click via jquery using `trigger()`

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I want to call Server side click event instead of Client Side. And my approach is to do not use Web method for UserControl.

Comment: _"Server side click event"_ ? I have never heard that before :(

Comment: Event form ucgTest.ascx.cs

Comment: Nikunj `trigger("click")` will call your server side click event

Comment: if you are talking about server side event why use ajax at all?

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava can you please share some code or reference so I can check example. Put your code in answer instead of comment.Thanks.

Comment: follow this https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/

Comment: @madalinivascu, Because I have complex UI and don't want to spoil other code. and don't want any update panel to manage postbacks.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava as per suggestion, It enables native browser events not aspx.cs methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to `presume` which `click` you are referring.
Assuming the `button` is present in the newly loaded `HTML` and a `click` event is attached to that button.

In this case you have to `delegate` the `event` and make this change

```
$('body').on('click',"id/class",function(event){
  //Rest of the code
})
```

where id/class is id or class of the button where click event will be attached.It can also be any other identifier